# Python Machine Learning - Rule based match

Tags: python, match

I am new to machine learning and need help on the best approach.

I have a master dataset with millions of rows with columns:

```
Customer first name, 
last name, 
SSN , 
address,
Unique cust id
```

Input is a new customer details with same columns.I want to create a machine learning model with following rules

```
If new customer matches any customer on SSN then return cust ids of
    matching customers  
else if customer matches any customer on First +
    Last name + zip then return cust ids of matching customers  
else
    create new cust id
```

The other issue is that name and address could have spelling errors, so exact match is not an option

what is the best approach and what model will work

Comment: Welcome! SQL would be more appropriate for this problem than machine learning. See "*No, you don't need ML/AI. You need SQL*": https://cyberomin.github.io/startup/2018/07/01/sql-ml-ai.html

Comment: Machine learning won't be of any help for this kind of task. It sounds like you want to set up a database with your data and then query things based on the conditions you wrote down.

Comment: Thanks, The other issue is that name and address could have spelling errors, so exact match is not an option

Comment: No ML is needed.ML could be useful just if you had a noisy database and you want to find similar (duplicated) customers (i.e. John Gates signed up 2 years ago and misspelled its name as Jon Gates, now he register with its right name)

Comment: (*Following edit*) This is more of a "fuzzy matching" problem. "Probabilistic Soft Logic" might be worth looking into (https://psl.linqs.org/).

Answer (score 1):

According to your update, you really want to search for similar customer.
If so you could:

- Compute some features representation for each set of fields (i.e. by composing meaningful string and using word2vec)
- Perform a similarity search (i.e. cosine similarity)
- Define a threshold acceptable to you to interpret that similarity and acts as a consequence

For scalability reasons I would compute the features offline (once a week for example).